# Linq query of XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So I'm trying to write a simple query that grabs all of a certain attribute from an XML file, but nothing seems to work. I've been able to do this with several other XML's but for some reason the one I'm working with here just won't cooperate. Any suggestions or advice would be hugely appreciated.

Here's what the XML looks like.

```
<Doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Name" xsi:schemaLocation="[there's a link here]" Name="Name">
<Wrapper>
<Box_Collection>
<Box name="Test A" test="Test B"/>
<Box name="Test C" test="Test D"/>
<Box name="Test E" test="Test F"/>
</Box_Collection>
</Wrapper>
</Doc>
```

Here's my C# code:

```
        XDocument customers = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\folder\file.xml");

        IEnumerable<string> names =
            from c in customers.Descendants("Box").Attributes("name")
            select c.Value;

        string nameList = "Names:";


        foreach (string c in names)
        {
            namer += " " + c;
        }

        textBox.AppendText(nameList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your XML has default namespace declared at the root element :

```
xmlns="Name"
```

XML elements inherit ancestor default namespace by default, unless otherwise specified (f.e by using explicit prefix that point to different namespace URI). You can use *`XNamespace` + element's local name* to point to element in namespace :

```
XNamespace ns = "Name";
IEnumerable<string> names =
            from c in customers.Descendants(ns+"Box").Attributes("name")
            select c.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your document has a default namespace of "Name". You need to reference the namespace when selecting a node like so:

```
    IEnumerable<string> names =
        from c in customers.Descendants(XName.Get("Box", "Name")).Attributes("name")
        select c.Value;
```